# Get all the endpoints from AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud

I have multiple AWS accounts in my organization they are using multiple services like ec2, s3,sns, eks, etc.. I want scrap all the default endpoints / domains created by AWS it self. for example; Whenever we creates EKS cluster aws automatically gives it API endpoint. I want that endpoint. I have all the privilege whatever requires is there any API / CLI command or any tool to do this work?

I have searched about API to scrap it. but no luck also I checked awscli but it returns mostly region and other details not the domain / url I'm looking for.